# How do ranges in dash work?

Tags: shell-script, dash, brace-expansion

I'm trying to figure out how to rush the following bash script in dash.

```
for x in {1..5}
do
    for y in {a..c}
    do
    echo $HOME$x$y
    done
done
```

Dash does not support brace expansion and I don't know of any other way of  obtaining a range-like construct in order to mimic the script above. I suppose I could get by with a while loop, but I wouldn't consider that to be a script adaptation, but an entirely different beast.

Is it possible to keep the spirit of the script above in Dash? Is it possible to keep the spirit of the script above without using external programs like seq? How?

Comment: in that simple example, you can just enumerate them: `a b c`, `1 2 3 4 5` ;-) In a real life setting, you would probably use sth more efficient than nested shell loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace Expansion is not defined by POSIX per se, you need to make use of options from other POSIX complaint tools for the conversion. One such way would be to use the ASCII table to map the conversion from the characters' ASCII values to their character value using `printf()`.  Look up `man ascii` for the value mappings.

```
i=1
asciiStart=97
asciiEnd=99
while [ "$i" -le 5 ]
do
    while [ "$asciiStart" -le "$asciiEnd" ]
    do
        echo "$HOME$i$(printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$asciiStart")")"
        asciiStart=$((asciiStart + 1))
    done
    asciiStart=97
    i=$(( i + 1 )) 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, since if there was another feature that did what brace expansion does, there would be be no need for brace expansion...

Note that if your lists are not static (e.g. the upper limit varies), then you can't easily use brace expansion in Bash either, since `{1..$n}` doesn't do what you want (braces expand *before* variables).

On the other hand, if your lists *are* static, it's not hard to just use some other program to create the lists and insert them directly on the script, so you'd just end up with:

```
for x in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    for y in a b c; do
        echo "$HOME$x$y"
    done
done
```

Using a `while` to generate a list of characters would also seem to be a bit difficult in the shell.

So, sorry, but this seems like something that would be easier done in some other language. Like Perl:

```
highnum=5 highchar=c perl -le 'for $x (1..$ENV{highnum}) { 
                                  for $y ("a"..$ENV{highchar}) { 
                                     print "$ENV{HOME}/$x$y"; } }'
```